# How many "of" is allowed? How to reposition nouns correctly?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, syntactic-analysis

Facing this, I am not sure that I know the right answer. At the university, I was taught that only 2 prepositions "of" are allowed to be sounding natural. If it comes to translation from Russian into English, it becomes hard since Russian is a syntactical language and there can be 3-4+ nouns in a row (in the Genitive case). I am not sure all nouns can be replaced in order to avoid many "of" in English. What is the rule here?

For example, "the level of reflexivity of representatives of other professions." Will it be okay to restructure it, say, into - "the level of reflexivity of other professions representatives (avoiding 1 of)" or "the other professions representatives' level of reflexivity (avoiding 2 of)" or "the other professions representatives' reflexivity level (avoiding all 3 of)"? What does make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Think of the limit of two "ofs" as a guideline and not as an absolute rule. Break it if you have to. All of your suggestions are worse than the original.

Comment: @Peter Shor's Sixth.